# Duplicate bullet points on unordered list item

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my unordered list look like this:

[image: Good List]

I am getting this (note the duplicate bullet point):

[image: Bad List]

My code reads as follows:

```html
<ul class="main-link">
  <li>
    <a href="">articles/</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="sub-link">
        <a href="">beliefs respect and facts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like the extra solid bullet point to be deleted some how. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "classes suck", "does oo sucks".....I think we might have a bigger problem than an extra bullet point :\

Comment: @S200 Lol. It is homework. I am suppose to mimic this webpage and it is someone else's content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove only one li tag, something like this:

```html
<ul class="main-link">
  <li>
    <a href="">articles/</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="sub-link">
        <a href="">beliefs respect and facts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Danny Holy cow. I totally knew this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the second `"ul"` inside the same `"li"`. Means it is also a part of first `"li"` content.

```html
<ul class="main-link">
  <li>
    <a href="">articles/</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="sub-link">
        <a href="">beliefs respect and facts</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-link">
        <a href="">beliefs respect and facts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```